# SQL to return matches and non-matches

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join

How do I return all the rows from two tables including the matches? For example, if I have a account table and order table with an account ID field in common I want to return the matches from both tables as well as the non-matches.

I am using SQL Server 2005

Thanks.

Comment: can you add sample records with your desired result? I'm confused with your statement: *I want to return the matches from both tables as well as the non-matches*

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but sgeddes code is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
  FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.AccountId = T2.AccountId
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks, that's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get both `MATCHED and UNMATCHED` records from both tables use `FULL JOIN` (or *FULL OUTER JOIN*). Also you can find what records are matched or unmatched using a `CASE` as below. [Sql-Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/faa69/8)

```
select isnull(a.accountId,o.accountId) accId, AccName,ProName,
       case when AccName+ProName is null then 'No'
            else 'Yes' end as IsMatched
from Accs a FULL JOIN Orders o on a.accountId = o.accountId
order by IsMatched 

--Example results
AccId   AccName ProName IsMatched
1       X       (null)  No
10      (null)  Apple   No
2       Y       Orange  Yes
3       Z       Mango   Yes
```